# Flutter dynamic creation RichText object from List<String>

Tags: flutter

There is a random list whose length is not constant. For example

```
  List<String> exampleList = List<String>();
   exampleList.add("one");
   exampleList.add("second random line");
   exampleList.add("third random line");
```

Depending on the content of the `exampleList[index]`, which is generated randomly, it is necessary to change the appearance, design, styles etc. If you use `RichText TextSpan`, then already hardcoded data is transferred there, and I need to generate this `RichText` dynamically. Any ideas on this?

approximate result of formating

```
 child: RichText(
               text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'GitHub is a development platform inspired by the way you work. From ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(text: 'op_n',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                   ),
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {
                                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                      content: Text("Sending Message"),
                                    ));
                                  }
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: ' to ',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  )
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'busin_ss,',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {
                                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                      content: Text("Sending Message"),
                                    ));
                                  }
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: ' you can host and review code, manage projects, and build software alongside 36 million developers.',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    )
                            )
                          ]
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what would be the result of the dynamically created RichText?

Comment: Hi. It is a regular text in which some special words are bold and clickable. But I don't know in advance where these words will be located. I need to generate on the fly RichText. I updated the question and added an example

Comment: How do you decide which text will have which style ? Based on index, based on extra info in the list ? How ? That's the important question. If you know this, you can simply iterate trough the list of items, check with ```if```s what style you should apply to them and you'll get a list of ```TextSpan``` that you can pass to RichText.

Comment: @danypata It doesn't matter how I define it, the main thing for me is to return the dynamic RichText. Let all even elements have a different style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample, I see that you define each part of your `RichText` with a `text`, a `style`, and optionally a `callback`.

You could use a `List<MyText>` instead of a `List<String>`:

```
class MyText {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final void Function(BuildContext) callback;

  MyText({
    this.text,
    this.style,
    this.callback,
  });
}

List<MyText> textSpanList = [
  MyText(
    text:
        'GitHub is a development platform inspired by the way you work. From ',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
  ),
  MyText(
    text: 'op_n',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    callback: (context) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Sending Message"),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  MyText(
    text: ' to ',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
  ),
  MyText(
    text: 'busin_ss,',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    callback: (context) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Sending Message"),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  MyText(
    text:
        ' you can host and review code, manage projects, and build software alongside 36 million developers.',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
  ),
];
```

And then use the `List<MyText>` as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(body: MyWidget()),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: textSpanList
              .map(
                (data) => data.callback == null
                    ? TextSpan(
                        text: data.text,
                        style: data.style,
                      )
                    : TextSpan(
                        text: data.text,
                        style: data.style,
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () => data.callback(context),
                      ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great Thanks! Highly detailed solution